# Dropbox coreApi adding Java Source Attachment

Tags: dropbox-api

I read the https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android article, but i cant do the foolowing steps:
Attaching source in Eclipse

Find the dropbox-android-sdk JAR file in the Package Explorer under Referenced Libraries.
Right-click on the JAR and select Properties.
Select Java Source Attachment from the sidebar.
Click External File and browse to the downloaded SDK .zip file.

Is it change (in eclipse) or not required anymore?

Comment: I found the alternative way to access to the Source Attachment  of the jar:
Go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and expand JRE System Library [your jre version] then, rt.jar. Select Source attachment, click Edit…. Select the source code file (External File…) and press OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropbox Android CoreApi trying to upload a file and get "Source not found'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954249/dropbox-android-coreapi-trying-to-upload-a-file-and-get-source-not-found)